# How to download scikit-image 0.13.1 in Pycharm?

Tags: python, magento, pip, pycharm, scikit-image

I tried to download this version

```
pip install scikit-image==0.13.1
```

on python 3.8.1 and pip 20.3.3 but it failed with this error message:

```
Command errored out with exit status 1:
Collecting scikit-image==0.13.1
Using cached scikit-image-0.13.1.tar.gz (26.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.7.3 in c:\users\wasim\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image==0.13.1) (1.15.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=1.8 in c:\users\wasim\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image==0.13.1) (2.5)
    Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=2.1.0 in c:\users\wasim\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image==0.13.1) (8.1.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: PyWavelets>=0.4.0 in c:\users\wasim\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\lib\site-packages (from scikit-image==0.13.1) (1.1.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in c:\users\wasim\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\lib\site-packages (from networkx>=1.8->scikit-image==0.13.1) (4.4.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\wasim\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\lib\site-packages (from PyWavelets>=0.4.0->scikit-image==0.13.1) (1.19.4)
    Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-image
      Building wheel for scikit-image (setup.py): started
      Building wheel for scikit-image (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
      Running setup.py clean for scikit-image
    Failed to build scikit-image
    Installing collected packages: scikit-image
        Running setup.py install for scikit-image: started
        Running setup.py install for scikit-image: finished with status 'error'
    
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Users\wasim\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\wasim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-igu2ekz7\\scikit-image_8689f1c3cfe0441c98c99d96a183386e\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\wasim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-igu2ekz7\\scikit-image_8689f1c3cfe0441c98c99d96a183386e\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\wasim\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-s45lpfni'
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-image/0.13.1/#files) you can see scikit-image 0.13.1 doesn't support python3.8.

So you need to downgrade your python version or upgrade scikit-image version.

Answer (score 0):

For the most recent compatible version:

```
python -m pip install -U scikit-image
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).